# Newly installed OS missing grub

Tags: grub, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint 15 With live usb alongside my old fedora 19 on my Server but it doesn't show up in grub. it shows up when I use OS prober:

```
$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sda5:Linux Mint 15 Olivia (15):LinuxMint:linux
```

But not in the grub bootscreen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you select "Install grub" when installing Linux Mint? Are those the results from running `os-prober` from within Mint, or from within Fedora? What happens if you run `sudo update-grub` from Fedora?

Comment: OS-prober results are from within fedora I can't even figure out how to boot mint since its not on the grub menu. sudo: update-grub: command not found

Comment: Try installing `update-grub` first: `sudo yum install update-grub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Fedora installation, run the following:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This will update your grub configuration and you should see your new system in the menu.